# Stored Procedure - Need to use the result of a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

The following stored procedure will return a result with a column `NoOfArticles` with the correct total amount.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_membersarea`(IN reqdTable varchar(30), IN ScannerID INT, IN MemberID INT)
BEGIN
declare NoOfArticles INT(11); 

SET @sql_text = concat("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfArticles FROM t_annualdetails WHERE ScannerID = ", ScannerID);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

So-far-so-good. Here is my problem. I would like to be able to use this 'result' in another query within the same Stored Procedure, but I don't know how to achieve it. I would like it to work something like this:

```
SET @NoOfArticles = NoOfArticles;   

SET @sql_text = concat("UPDATE ", reqdTable, " SET Scan = ", @NoOfArticles, " WHERE MemberID = ", MemberID);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, but I would like the 'result' (`NoOfArticles`) to be placed in a variable (i.e. `@NoOfArticles`), and then use that variable (`@NoOfArticles`) inside an `UPDATE` statement.

I've been on this all day with no success. I'd be grateful for some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: ***WHAT*** database ??

Comment: MySQL database is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `INTO`, not `AS`

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_membersarea`(IN reqdTable varchar(30), IN ScannerID INT, IN MemberID INT)
BEGIN
declare NoOfArticles INT(11); 
/*----------------------------------here-v--into-instead-of-as-----------------*/
SET @sql_text = concat("SELECT COUNT(*) INTO NoOfArticles FROM t_annualdetails WHERE ScannerID = ", ScannerID);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @NoOfArticles = NoOfArticles;    
SET @sql_text = concat("UPDATE ", reqdTable, " SET Scan = ", @NoOfArticles, " WHERE MemberID = ", MemberID);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;

/*you can also use parameters, but not for tablename*/
SET @sql_text = concat("UPDATE ", reqdTable, " SET Scan = ? WHERE MemberID = ?");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt USING NoOfArticles, MemberID;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT:**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_membersarea`(IN reqdTable varchar(30), IN ScannerID INT, IN MemberID INT)
BEGIN

SET @sql_text = concat("SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @NoOfArticles FROM t_annualdetails WHERE ScannerID = ", ScannerID);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

/*you can also use parameters, but not for tablename*/
SET @sql_text = concat("UPDATE ", reqdTable, " SET Scan = ? WHERE MemberID = ?");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt USING @NoOfArticles, MemberID;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @fancyPants. Unfortunately, I am now getting the error message: 'Error Code: 1327 Undeclared variable: NoOfArticles'. 

I wasn't quite sure if this 'NoOfArticles' referred to the one in the SELECT statement or the 'at-sign' NoOfArticles. So I changed the 'at-sign' NoOfArticles to 'at-sign' TotalArticles (in the UPDATE line as well), and I received exactly the same error message.

I am very new to Stored Procedures (but okay with SQL) and I am using 'MySQL Workbench' so maybe there's some setting that needs to be in place (or is assumed) but I'm not executing it. Thanks

Comment: That's really strange. Please have a try with the version I edited into my answer.

Comment: Aaargh! Apologies @fancyPants. I blinking removed your edit by mistake, thinking it was the edit that I had just made, that was just plain wrong. If you can remember what you changed that would be great. In the meantime, I'll be heading for the nearest cliff-top where the 'silly-people' go :(

Comment: It's still here. Your suggested edit was rejected ;)

Comment: YEEEEEES! I found your edit by clicking the 'Active' tab. It didn't work straight away because the EXECUTE USING variables must be prefixed with the 'at-sign'. So I simply added a SET command prior to the UPDATE field and it worked.

`code`
SET @MemberID = MemberID;

/*you can also use parameters, but not for tablename*/
SET @sql_text = concat("UPDATE ", reqdTable, " SET Scanned = ? WHERE MemberID = ?");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt USING @NoOfArticles, @MemberID;
`code`

Seriously, thank you :) I have been at this for over a day now, and it was getting a bit depressing.

Comment: Dammit. I can't +1 you. My rep isn't good enough. Sorry, but a massive thank you :)